# Google Maps vs CSS transition

Tags: css

I've got a problem with embedded Google Maps and CSS transition which is set to

```
*{ transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }
```

This makes map shake while dragging. After disabling transition everything works fine but the transition needs to be set to all elements in this case. Is there a solution to easily disable it for map layer and all children loaded later by Google script?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS [**:not** selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

```
*:not(.maps){ transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }
```

Comment: If this would be such easy... :) Unfortunately this does not work. It unset transition only for the map container but not for children and the wrong effect remains.

Comment: Did you try applying `.child { transition: inherit}` to the child elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
.map-container {
    div{
        transition-duration: initial;
    }
}
```

or

```
.map-container {
     div{
         transition-duration: 0s;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**